# cutting of raster image to selected extent?

Tags: r, clip

I have taken raster images from worldclim and I want to cut this raster image to Canada latitude and longitude (42,83, 53,141). I am new user in R so can anyone tell me how I cut this on R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crop()` function from the package `raster`:

```
library(raster)
canada_cropped = crop(x = full_raster_image, y = your_extension)
```

Here `x` can be your raster image that you want to crop from, and `y` is the `extent` object (or an object you can extract from).

I would recommend using `?raster::crop` where you can learn a lot more about this.

Comment: on y I need to add my (42,83 53,141)?